# How to downgrade php7 to php5.6 in mac high sierra

Tags: php

Have a zend file which is perfectly go over php5.x but when it move with mac high sierra where getting error , I found that there is php 7 so want to downgrade 7 to 5.6

Answer (score 13):

1) On the Terminal:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

2) Then, open the file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` with `read/write` permissions and change the following lines:

Change the line:

`LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`

To that:

```
#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

3) Pay attention because when you upgraded your macOS Sierra to macOS Sierra High, in `apache2` folder, the previous file `http.conf` still in there but with another name. You can see and compare both for a correct configuration of your PHP 5.6.
Usually, the line `DocumentRoot`, `<Directory "/some_local/">` and `LoadModule` were changed by the macOS upgrade, just compare what you had and change that according to you'd like the Apache/PHP behaves.

4) Restart your apache:

On the Terminal again, type it:
`sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart`

Comment: Thanks. That `<IfModule mod_php5.c>` tag was crucial for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are desperately tired and couldn't stop biting your nails to find a solution in order to install php5.6 on MAC likes me. Please have a look at [this awesome article](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-mojave-apache-multiple-php-versions). Which allows me to see the light at the end of the tunnel.

There's no need to thank me in case you solve the problem, go there and give it to him. He deserves it.

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

you should definitely try `homebrew` (https://brew.sh) and it's awesome PHP packages like:

- `php@5.6`,
- `php@7.0`,
- `php@7.1`,
- `php` (which is latests version, currently 7.2).

I am using it for years and it is awesome.

Here is good tutorial:

https://medium.com/@romaninsh/install-php-7-2-xdebug-on-macos-high-sierra-with-homebrew-july-2018-d7968fe7e8b8

Have fun!

Comment: FYI, both the 5.6 and 7.0 versions have been removed from Homebrew core